# Escape dot (.) from I18n translation look up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

Is there anyway I can escape the I18n dot?
I have keys that contain dots and can't seem to figure out a way to do a lookup correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply break your dotted keys into the tree structure?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm pulling the key names from a database and it'd be easier if they match

Comment: I still think you should try to fix the keys which you are getting from database instead of trying to hack while accessing

Comment: thanks, thats one option. Another option is to escape the dot with an html entity. `&#46;`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think your answer is best bc its more legible and easier to do. if you want to put it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From my experience, when your datastore (mongodb or, in this case, i18n) treats dots in keys in a special way, the best way is to not fight it. My suggestion is to expand your dotted keys into a tree i18n expects. So this

```
projects.form.title: Create new project
```

becomes this

```
projects:
  form:
    title: Create new project
```

Or you could replace dots in your keys with, say, underscore. Replacing them with html entities (`&#46;`) or, worse, unicode look-alikes only leads to confusion and/or bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem loading translations from a non-YAML source where period syntax was more convenient than a tree relationship. You can use the below code to convert the keys as part of I18n loading (either in a `.rb` file in `I18n.load_path` or a custom backend).

```rb
require 'i18n/core_ext/hash'

# Raw, period-delineated keys (from a DB, API, etc.):
translations = {
  'a.b.c' => 'foo',
  'd.e.f' => 'bar'
}

translations.inject({}) { |hash, (key, value)|
  item = key.split('.').reverse.inject(value) { |v, k| { k => v } }
  hash.deep_merge!(item)
}
```

```
$ => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"foo"}}, "d"=>{"e"=>{"f"=>"bar"}}}
```